# Como contar ocorrências de uma substring em uma string em Python?

Tags: python, string

Como faço para ler duas strings e verificar o número de ocorrências da segunda string na primeira?

**Exemplo:** Se a primeira string digitada for `"abracadabra"` e a segunda `"bra"`, então o número de ocorrências será **2**.

Answer (score 7):

Use str.count:

```
 >>> nStr = 'abracadabra'
 >>> nStr.count('bra')
```

[Fonte - Determining how many times a substring occurs in a string in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11476713/determining-how-many-times-a-substring-occurs-in-a-string-in-python)

[Python, Tutorials](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_count.htm)

Answer (score 0):

```
frase = str(input("Digite a frase a se analisada: "))
palavra = str(input("Ocorrências da palavra/letra: "))

resultado = frase.count(palavra)

print(f"Na frase |{frase}|, a palavra/letra |{palavra}| apareceu {resultado} vezes")
```